# Elementary won't boot with a QHD monitor

Tags: boot, system, graphic-drivers, grub

i have installed Elementary on my NUC-8-i7 about 6 months ago. Everything was working perfectly for me and i had no issues. Recently I upgraded my monitor to a QHD monitor and suddenly it won't boot... Seems that this is something to do with the monitor as if i bring back my old monitor, it boots.
I also tried a fresh install on a different HD, but event the installer won't boot.

Comment: Are you sure the monitor works? Can you get into the BIOS/EFI configuration screens with that monitor connected? Is it connected via the same method as the previous monitor (DVI, DisplayPort, HDMI, etc)?

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue with ubuntu 18 install. All flavors of ubuntu 18 I have tried are failing to start installation. Only success I had was installing ubuntu server 16 that has a CUI setup, the manually installing the ubuntu desktop via apt. Oh, and also tried it on my daughter computer with the same issue. Windows installation is working so I guess it is something with the installer GUI mode/driver. Is there a way to switch to none GUI installer?

Comment: Figured out it is something to do with the UEFI install, if i disable UEFI in the bios, the installer starts as expected. Have no idea how is this related to the QHD monitor.